# Free UK Geocoding with Java

Tags: java, geocoding, software-recommendations, united-kingdom

Is there any free solution for geocoding UK with Java?

I would like to avoid APIs, like for example Google's Geocode service as I have over 1 million addresses to geocode.

Comment: Perhaps this [website](http://jgeocoder.sourceforge.net/) might be helpful? Seems it was tested on US addresses but perhaps it can be tweaked for UK...

Comment: I already checked it. Then I should use data from OpenStreetMap? I need a OSM parser too I guess.